# PHP to get specific text from plain text

Tags: php, html, dom

Here is the text value i am trying to search, this text don't have ant HTML in it( thats th problem HTML DOM not working)

```
    User Guide
    For iOS 7.1 Software
    Contents
    Chapter 1: New One

    iPhone at a Glance
    iPhone
    overview
    Accessories
    Multi-Touch screen
    Buttons
    Status icons
    Chapter 2 Second One this is long
    Chapter 3 new this is long
```

Ok now i am trying to get  `Chapter 1: New One` and `Chapter 2 Second One this is long` kind of values, there are more Chapter to get.

I was trying PHP Simple HTML DOM, but don't know how to extract these Chapters with `different format` and `length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean something like this ...?

```
<?php

$lines = "    User Guide
    For iOS 7.1 Software
    Contents
    Chapter 1: New One

    iPhone at a Glance
    iPhone
    overview
    Accessories
    Multi-Touch screen
    Buttons
    Status icons
    Chapter 2 Second One this is long
    Chapter 3 new this is long";

$lines = explode("\r\n", $lines);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    if (!empty($line)) {
        if (preg_match('/Chapter \\d/', $line)) {
            echo $line ."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Chapter 1: New One
Chapter 2 Second One this is long
Chapter 3 new this is long
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no DOM so using methods for that won't help. You can use `array_filter` and `explode`.

```
$chapters = array_filter(explode("\r\n", $lines), function ($line) {
  $line = trim($line);
  return substr($line, 0, 7) === 'Chapter';
});
```

Then `$chapters` should look something like this:

```
array(
  "Chapter 1: New One",
  "Chapter 2 Second One this is long",
  "Chapter 3 new this is long"
);
```

My PHP is kind of rusty, but should get you close!